# Negative lookbehind or something else?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The following pattern will capture file names which has suffix and specified extension.
`'/(.+?)(@2x|~ipad|@2x~ipad)\.(jpg|png)/mi'`

This is example list of files

```
SLN0098H@2x.JPG
SLN0098H~ipad.JPG
SLN0098H_thumb@2x~ipad.JPG
SLN0098H_thumb@2x.JPG
SLN0098H_thumb~ipad.JPG
SLN0099H@2x~ipad.JPG
SLN0099H@2x.JPG
SLN0099H~ipad.JPG
SLN0098H_t@2x.JPG
SLN0098H_cover@2x.JPG
```

However, I want to exclude those **lines**, which contains `_cover`, `_thumb`, `_t`, `_c` before file name resolution suffix. Is it possible to do within regex or do I have to loop&filter manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead to avoid matching few strings:

```
/^((?!.*?_(?:cover|thumb|t|c)\b).+?)(?:@2x|~ipad|@2x~ipad)\.(?:jpg|png)$/mi
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/xV6nW2/2)

Here `((?!.*?_(?:cover|thumb|t|c)\b)` is the **negative lookahead** that will avoid matching the input if it contains any of `_cover, _thumb, _t, _c` in it,

Comment: What unwanted items did you find it capturing?

Comment: Lines containing _c, _t etc.

Comment: Oh you just need to use anchors `^` and `$` (see updated regex with a demo link)

Comment: there we go! now this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Pablo: Is this regex not matching your requirement in some way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regex **discard** technique.

For example using this regex:

```
.*(?:_cover|_thumb|_t|_c)|^(?:(.+?)(@2x|~ipad|@2x~ipad)\.(jpg|png))$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fK9xY0/1)**

The idea is to use this technique:

> discard patt1 | discard patt1 | discard patt1 | **(grab content needed)**  <-- Notice the last match is a capturing group.

[image]

So, for your case the idea is:

```
Discard below patterns:
.*                        Whatever content that contains:     
( _cover                   '_cover'
 |                        OR
  _thumb                   '_thumb'
 |                        OR
  _t                       '_t'
 |                        OR
  _c                       '_c' 
)

But keep the pattern you want:
|^(?:(.+?)(@2x|~ipad|@2x~ipad)\.(jpg|png))$
```

Debuggex does a very good job showing this technique:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

In this image you can clearly view that the content you want is captured by capturing groups whilst above pattern means *discard all these matches*. For me it's an excellent technique that help regex to be very clean.

Hope to help

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, but this does not filter out unwanted items(containing _c, _t etc). It captures everything.

Comment: @Pablo you have to check at match information http://regex101.com/r/fK9xY0/1. The technique is to use the content of the capturing group. In the screenshot I've put on my answer the green matches are the grabbed one. You can put the regex you want I only used your regex but added at the beginning the discarded patterns

Comment: sorry, wrong comment initially came here, so I corrected later.  Your technique is grabbing groups fine, but NOT discarding those with _t, _c matches... I don't need to capture those lines at all.

Comment: @Pablo you can see in the screenshot that SLN0098H_t@2x.JPG is discarded and SLN0098H_cover@2x.JPG as well. I marked it with red arrows. Btw, I also put the link to the [working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fK9xY0/1)

Comment: I think we are not on the same page. You can see in your screenshot that the first part of "discarded" line is still captured. I need to completely ignore those lines. In your regex they are matching!

Comment: georg's answer is perfectly discarding those unwanted items, but there I lose my old capturing groups.

Comment: @Pablo I don't see any Georg on the thread. What are you looking at? This is your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508209/negative-lookbehind-or-something-else.

Comment: Unfortunately he deleted his answer for some reason. Anyway, I modified a little his version `^(\w(?!_(?:cover|thumb|t|c)))+(@2x|~ipad|@2x~ipad)+\.(jpg|png)$` and here I only miss one part! First capturing group should capture string from the beginning, but it does capture only 1 character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60018/discussion-between-fede-and-pablo).

Comment: @Pablo just a last attempt I want to check with you, is this what you want? http://regex101.com/r/fK9xY0/3

Comment: @Fede: This latest regex will not match `SLN_0098H@2x.JPG` I don't think OP wants to exclude any `_`

Comment: @Pablo so, I think you want this: http://regex101.com/r/fK9xY0/4 if that's what you want, let me know and I can update my answer

Comment: @Fede: almost there, just need to stick with 3 capturing groups I had initially for base name(in your regex it captures only 1 letter), suffix(~ipad etc) and extension.

Comment: But it will match `_t@2x.JPG` which should not be matches as per OP

Comment: @Pablo I think you should create a new question or modify this one. Becase there are many ways to achieve what you asked on this question but you need something really specific. Btw, I'll keep trying.